# Jquery datepicker selected date not assigning the value

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, datepicker

I have a date picker associated with an editor field for selecting the date. But when i select the date, the selection is showing in the editor field but the value is not getting assigned to the respective element.

My code is as follows:

jQuery:

```
$("#JobDate").click(function () {
    $(this).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' }).datepicker("show");
});
```

cshtml code

```
<tr class="spaceUnder">
    <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.JobDate)</td>
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.JobDate)</td>
</tr>
```

I would also like to hear your approach on this one. Alternative methods are also welcome.

Comment: Your code is not making sense - why are you assigning the plugin each time you click it. You initialize it once using `$("#JobDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' })`

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
$('#JobDate").datepicker({
    //your configuration here
});
```

This assigns handlers to handle setting the value of your input when you select a date.

Comment: I need to show only the datepicker on clicking the editor field

Comment: Sorry.  I misread the question.  So what is the field you want the value assigned to?

Comment: Editor filed will be there. on click a date picker should be displayed and selected date should be assigned to the element associated with the editor field. date picker is showing but value isn't assigned.

Comment: When you say the editor field, you mean the input right?

Comment: The jquery  in my answer will create a date picker that is shown when clicking the input that assigns the value to the input when it is selected

Answer (score 1):

To assign a value for a datepicker you should send an 'update' action into it:

```
$my_input.datepicker('update', new Date(my_date))
```