# Why aren't datepicker values assigning the form input a value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am having a similar if not the same problem as this question:
[Jquery datepicker selected date not assigning the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40309366/jquery-datepicker-selected-date-not-assigning-the-value)

However the answer given is next to useless.

I have an asp.net MVC application where details are sent from a form in the view to the controller but when debugging the values are just default DateTime values.

On inspection the values aren't being assigned when either typed in or when using the JQuery UI datepicker.
[image: Input with assigned value but no value in source]

Using this script to utilise the Jquery-ui Datepicker

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#startDatePicker").datepicker();
    $("#endDatePicker").datepicker();
})
</script>
```

Here is the code creating the form this is encapsulated in @using (Html.BeginForm()){ }

```
        <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.End_Date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.End_Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id= "endDatePicker" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.End_Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Help would be appreciated even explaining why this is happening

Thanks.

Edit - Model:

```
 public partial class BPO
 {
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public BPO()
    {
        this.Order_Log = new HashSet<Order_Log>();
    }

    [Display(Name = "BPO")]
    public string BPO_ID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Start Date")]
    public System.DateTime Start_Date { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "End Date")]
    public System.DateTime End_Date { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "In Use")]
    public bool In_Use { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Used For")]
    public string Used_For { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Order_Log> Order_Log { get; set; }
}
```

Edit 2 - The Controller methods:

```
/**
     * Returns a View
     */
    public ActionResult AddBPO()
    {
        return View();  //Returns AddBPO.cshtml
    }

    /**
     * Adds a BPO Number to the BPO Database
     * @Param pO The BPO Number passed by POST
     */
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddBPO(BPO pO)
    {
        try
        {
            SFI.BPOes.Add(pO);                      //Add pO to the BPO Table
            SFI.SaveChanges();                      //Save the changes to the Database
            return RedirectToAction("RequestItem"); //Redirect to RequestItem
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = ex.Message;   //Set the error message to the ViewBag
            return View(pO);                //Return AddBPO.cshtml with the data pO
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show your model

Comment: Can you post your model and controller

Comment: is this happening for both start and end date which have datatype as datetime

Comment: Yep, the only thing successfully being passed is the BPO_ID

Comment: So I am not seeing where you're assigning the selected value anywhere on the Date Picker click event or what have you.  In the referenced Stack Overflow article you can see the click event.

Comment: The image of your html shows `value=""` for your `End_Date` property which is simply not possible for the property is `DateTime` (not nullable). You have not shown us all the relevant code

Comment: Not sure if this would work but your input's id is the endDatePicker.  This is where the jQuery datepicker is initialized and the where the value for is assigned.  Somehow you have to link this to your model.  
What you'll be looking for is something like so:
model.End_Date = $('#endDatePicker').val(); on the click event for your endDatePicker.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have shown you all the code that is associated with that page.

Comment: @DylanWright in regards to your first comment the onclick event is to make the datepicker "pop up" I have tried this but the datepicker would not even show up as an input doesn't seem to have an onclick event. Thank you for your comments I will try the second one now and let you know how it goes!

Comment: @DylanWright I have messed around with finding a way to link the datepicker and the model together but realised that was pointless as the value of the textbox is the relation to the model. The issue is not with the model or the controller as they are unrelated to the issue, the issue is the Editorfor element and the (unknown) reason why the value of the <input> is not being update when typed into or the when using the datepicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a fix. (More of a workaround ***See edit for actual fix***)

The dates were being passed via post but were not being converted into a datetime as they were not in the correct format

To fix this we get the Data directly from POST
`Request["Start_Date"]`
`Request["End_Date"]`

Then Format the data into a string parsable by System.DateTime

```
private string FormatToDate(String date)
{
    string formattedDate = date.Substring(6,4) +"/"+ date.Substring(0,2) + "/" + date.Substring(3,2) +" 00:00:00.000";
    return formattedDate;
}
```

This is the final code that fixed it

```
BPO newBPO = new BPO()
{
    BPO_ID = bPO.BPO_ID,
    Start_Date = DateTime.Parse(FormatToDate(Request["Start_Date"].ToString())),
    End_Date = DateTime.Parse(FormatToDate(Request["End_Date"].ToString()))
};
```

Edit:

## Fix

#### *(Non-Workaround)*

Set the DataType in the model using DataAnnotations.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[Display(Name ="Start Date")]
public DateTime Start_Date { get; set; }
```

This will provide a datepicker making the jquery-ui api redundant and allow the data to be passed via POST

Answer (score 0):

Try this
`@Html.EditorFor(model => model.End_Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id= "endDatePicker" } })`

Comment: That makes no difference at all. And you only need the `@` in `htmlAttributes` when its a reserved key word (such as `class`)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(function () {
         $("[id$=input__Dob]").datepicker({
             dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
             showOn: 'button',
             buttonImageOnly: true,
             buttonImage: '../Images/calender.png'
         });
     });
```

// input__Dob : textbox id
and buttonImage side to textbox is calender.png
make sure image is there in folder